Newly created aspects not visible when attaching to assets in Dataplex Catalog UI
When attempting to attach aspects to assets/entities in the new Dataplex Catalog interface, I walked through the following steps: Set up Lakes/zones, added Assets, created Aspect Types, Entry Types, Taxonomies, Attributes + Child attributes. I have proper permissions to perform these actions as well as the proper Dataplex permissions, but when I attempt to add new Aspects to a column or table, they do not appear. I'm not finding good documentation on how to troubleshoot aside from clearing cache, checking permissions and ensuring Aspects are added to an Entry Group. All of these have been ruled out as possible causes and the aspects are simply not populating when I search through the list.
clearing cache, checking permissions and ensuring Aspects are added to an Entry Group

Ensure when creating new Aspect types that the dataset and the aspect types are within the same region. Additionally, within the new Dataplex Catalog UI, you will need to access to dataset via 'search' and not through the lakes and zones. Once you find your dataset within the search, you will be able to see and attach all aspects that are available within the same region as your dataset.
